# Insert text between title and author

Tags: titles

I'm writing a book review, and I'm trying to follow the style template, after which the bibliographic details about the book I'm reviewing go in between the title (which is simply 'Review') and my author details. I'm customizing `\maktetitle` with `titling` (the package documentation is not an easy read, so I might be doing that wrongly).

What can I do to add something between the title and my author details?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
    \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\textbf}
    \posttitle{\vskip .25ex\hrule\par\end{flushleft}}
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large}
    \postauthor{\par\end{flushleft}}
    \predate{\begin{flushleft}}
    \postdate{\par\end{flushleft}}
\begin{document}

\title{Review}
% The bibliographic details about the book I'm reviewing go between the title and my author details.
\author{\textbf{Paul McCartney}\\ University of Liverpool}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\noindent Here my review begins
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personalize at will:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\textbf}
\posttitle{\vskip .25ex\hrule\end{flushleft}}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large}
\postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
\predate{\begin{flushleft}}
\postdate{\end{flushleft}}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookb{%
  \begin{quote}
  \thebookdata
  \end{quote}
  }
\newcommand{\thebookdata}{Missing book data} % default value
\newcommand{\bookdata}[2]{%
  \renewcommand\thebookdata{{\large{#1}\par}#2}%
}
\begin{document}

\title{Review}
\author{\textbf{Paul McCartney}\\ University of Liverpool}
\date{\today}

\bookdata{Book title}{by A. Uthor}

\maketitle
\noindent Here my review begins
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I went with this. Follow-up question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136303/cant-break-a-line-in-maketitle-with-raggedright

Answer (score 1):

I would forego the using of titles when writing a review like this. One can create a similar layout without using any titles *and* it provides you more freedom in terms of the layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{titling,lipsum}
    \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\textbf}
    \posttitle{\vskip .25ex\hrule\par\end{flushleft}}
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large}
    \postauthor{\par\end{flushleft}}
    \predate{\begin{flushleft}}
    \postdate{\par\end{flushleft}}
\begin{document}

%%%% Old definition of Review

\title{Review}
% The bibliographic details about the book I'm reviewing go between the title and my author details.
\author{\textbf{Paul McCartney}\\ University of Liverpool}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\noindent Here my review begins

\clearpage

%%%% New definition of Review

\raggedright

\textbf{\LARGE Review}

\hrulefill
\medskip\par

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip

{\large\textbf{Paul McCartney}\par
University of Liverpool\par}

\medskip

\today

\bigskip

Here my review begins

\end{document}
```

A separate structure/content approach would include something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reviewtitle}[1]{\def\@reviewtitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\reviewtitleformat}[1]{\def\@reviewtitleformat{#1}}
\newcommand{\bookauthor}[1]{\def\@bookauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\bookauthorformat}[1]{\def\@bookauthorformat{#1}}
\newcommand{\booktitle}[1]{\def\@booktitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\booktitleformat}[1]{\def\@booktitleformat{#1}}
\newcommand{\reviewauthor}[1]{\def\@reviewauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\reviewauthorformat}[1]{\def\@reviewauthorformat{#1}}
\newcommand{\reviewauthorsub}[1]{\def\@reviewauthorsub{#1}}
\newcommand{\reviewauthorsubformat}[1]{\def\@reviewauthorsubformat{#1}}
\newcommand{\reviewdate}[1]{\def\@reviewdate{#1}}
\newcommand{\reviewdateformat}[1]{\def\@reviewdateformat{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  {\@reviewtitleformat\@reviewtitle}

  \hrulefill
  \medskip\par

  {\@booktitleformat\@booktitle\par}
  {\@bookauthorformat\@bookauthor\par}

  \bigskip

  {\@reviewauthorformat\@reviewauthor\par}
  {\@reviewauthorsubformat\@reviewauthorsub\par}

  \medskip

  {\@reviewdateformat\@reviewdate\par}

  \bigskip
}
\makeatother

\reviewtitle{Review}
\reviewtitleformat{\bfseries\LARGE}
\reviewauthor{Paul McCartney}
\reviewauthorformat{\bfseries\large}
\reviewauthorsub{University of Liverpool}
\reviewauthorsubformat{\large}
\booktitle{Book title \\ \lipsum[2]}
\booktitleformat{\itshape}
\bookauthor{Some Author}
\bookauthorformat{\bfseries}
\reviewdate{\today}
\reviewdateformat{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\maketitle

Here my review begins

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sympathetic to what you're suggesting, but I've also learned that everything having to do with 'style' should be expressed and defined in the preamble, and then the 'content' goes in the document. I guess I'm attempting to follow that principle.

Comment: @Sverre: Sure... I'll update the solution to accommodate such a request.

Comment: @Werner -- if a book review is to be published in a journal, it is often the case that the details of the book that is being reviewed will be pulled out automatically and entered into an aggregator database for retrieval.  in that case, it's essential that everything be "tagged" explicitly.  maybe not necessary for this particular review, but it's important to remember for when the occasion requires.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Good point.